# Why do I have to specify the Into implementation for one type and not another type?

Tags: rust, embedded, traits

I have these 2 structs

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vin {
    data: [u8; 17],
}

impl Vin {
    pub fn new(data: [u8; 17]) -> Vin {
        Vin { data }
    }
}

impl Into<[u8;17]> for Vin {
    fn into(self) -> [u8;17] {
        self.data
    }
}

#[derive(Copy, Clone, Debug, Eq, PartialEq)]
pub struct Vcu {
    data: [u8; 11],
}

impl Vcu {
    pub fn new(data: [u8; 11]) -> Vcu {
        Vcu { data }
    }

    pub fn as_string_utf8(&self) -> String {
        std::str::from_utf8(&self.data).unwrap().to_owned()
    }
}

impl Into<[u8;11]> for Vcu {
    fn into(self) -> [u8;11] {
        self.data
    }
}
```

But when I try to use the implementation of Into

```rust
let mut packet_data: [u8; 36] = [0; 36];
let a: &[u8] = <[u8;17]>::from(vin_number.clone().into()).as_ref();
let b: &[u8] = <[u8;11]>::from(serial_ecu.clone().into()).as_ref();
```

For the Vin type I don't have any problem but for the Vcu type it gives me the following error:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> 
   |
35 |         let b: &[u8] = <[u8;11]>::from(serial_ecu.clone().into()).as_ref();
   |                        ---------------                    ^^^^
   |                        |
   |                        required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `[u8; 11]: From<_>` found in the `core` crate:
           - impl<T> From<!> for T;
           - impl<T> From<(T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T)> for [T; 11];
           - impl<T> From<T> for T;
help: try using a fully qualified path to specify the expected types
   |
35 |         let b: &[u8] = <[u8;11]>::from(<motorcycle::Vcu as Into<T>>::into(serial_ecu.clone())).as_ref();
   |                                        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                  ~

error[E0283]: type annotations needed
   --> 
    |
35  |         let b: &[u8] = <[u8;11]>::from(serial_ecu.clone().into()).as_ref();
    |                                                           ^^^^
    |
note: multiple `impl`s satisfying `motorcycle::Vcu: Into<_>` found
   --> 
    |
112 | impl Into<[u8;11]> for Vcu {
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    = note: and another `impl` found in the `core` crate:
            - impl<T, U> Into<U> for T
              where U: From<T>;
help: try using a fully qualified path to specify the expected types
    |
35  |         let b: &[u8] = <[u8;11]>::from(<motorcycle::Vcu as Into<T>>::into(serial_ecu.clone())).as_ref();
    |                                        +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++                  ~
```

I have solved the problem as follows

```rust
let a: &[u8] = <[u8;17]>::from(vin_number.clone().into()).as_ref();
let b: &[u8] = <[u8;11]>::from(<self::Vcu as Into<[u8;11]>>::into(serial_ecu.clone())).as_ref();
```

But my question is why for one type I don't have any problems but for the other I do?

What I'm doing wrong?

Sorry if the question is stupid but I couldn't solve it.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using `X::from(y.into())` in the first place. The `from` call can accept multiple types and `.into()` can create multiple types so you're likely to hit an ambiguity.

Comment: Another thing: *"One should avoid implementing `Into` and implement `From` instead"* ([`Into`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html)). That is actually causing another level of confusion since `<[u8;_]>::from` can't actually use the implementation you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

The ambiguity arises because `From<(T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T)> for [T; 11]` is [implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#impl-From%3C(T,+T,+T,+T,+T,+T,+T,+T,+T,+T,+T)%3E-for-%5BT;+11%5D) for `N` up to `12` so the compiler could convert to a `[u8; 11]` from multple different types. That's not the case for `[u8; 17]` though.
You can simplify your life by just following the tips of the [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html)

> One should avoid implementing `Into` and implement `From` instead

```rust
impl From<Vcu> for [u8;11] {
    fn into(v: Vcu) -> [u8;11] {
        self.data
    }
}
```

and just use that implementation:

```rust
let b: &[u8] = <[u8;11]>::from(serial_ecu.clone()).as_ref();
```

Though in your case it would be even better to implement `AsRef<[u8;11]>` because the temporary created by `from` in the oneliner is immediately dropped so you can never use `b`.

With this `AsRef`:

```rust
impl AsRef<[u8; 11]> for Vcu {
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &[u8;11] {
        &self.data
    }
}
```

You can borrow from `serial_ecu` instead and use the resulting `b` as long as `serial_ecu` isn't mutably borrowed or moved:

```rust
fn main() {
    let serial_ecu = Vcu {
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
    };
    
    let b: &[u8] = serial_ecu.as_ref();
    dbg!(b);
}
```